# two digit number not getting displayed in nativescript label

Tags: javascript, xml, user-interface, observable, nativescript

I am having strange problem with my UI. I have barcode scanner in my phone so I am scanning barcode and storing it to observable array (That’s working fine). I also have one label where I am displaying length of array.
everytime I add new item the label text is changing as per length of array but once the length increase to 10 it’s stop displaying in UI.

XML

```
      <Label length="4" text="{{ qty }}" />
```

Javascript

```
      var qty = dockReceive.wayBills.length
      dockReceive.set("qty",qty);
```

model class dockReceive

```
var observableModule = require("data/observable");
var observableArrayModule = require("data/observable-array");

function DockReceive(info) {
 info = info || {};
console.log("in dock receive");

var viewModel = new observableModule.fromObject({

 wayBills: info.wayBills || new observableArrayModule.ObservableArray(),
 qty: info.qty || 00,
  }); 
  return viewModel;
  }
   module.exports = DockReceive;
```

Please help me to find out solution for this strange problem.

Comment: are you sure the label is wide enough on screen to hold the text?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon  yes there is plenty space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange but this is my solution. I added width property of label

```
       <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" row="3" column="0" id="wbcount" visibility="hidden">
       <Label text="Received Waybill(s) :  " width="55%" /><Label text="{{rwbqty}}" width="40%" />
       </StackLayout>
```